# File upload using react redux through API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-redux, redux-form

I would like to upload a file with the [react-redux-universal-hot-example](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) boilerplate.

On submit, the function below is called (managed by the [ApiClient](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/helpers/ApiClient.js)):

```
export function update(data) {
  return {
    types: [UPLOAD, UPLOAD_SUCCESS, UPLOAD_FAIL],
    promise: (client) => client.post('/project/update', {
      files: data
    })
  };
}
```

On the server side, the following function is called (managed by the [Api](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/api/api.js#L28)):

```
export default function update(req, params) {
  // get the file
}
```

Where are the file information located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an Express middleware for handling multipart/form-data, like [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).